# Using plotly with ggplot (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

I'm trying to integrate plotly in my code but the final result is different than what I get with ggplot.

I'm plotting temperature and humidity (from a data frame `df`) measurements taken in regular time intervals and saving it into an object that I plot again using plotly, like so:

```
april_temp <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(temp) &
  day >= '2020-04-01' &
  day <= '2020-04-30') %>%
  ggplot(aes(hour, temp, color = temp, group =  day)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 0.8) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = 'blue', high = 'orange') +
  facet_wrap(vars(dia))
```

This code, generates the following graphic(as expected):
[Daily temperatures from April](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3yeQ.png)

Plotly official documentation says that I can just plot I again by calling `ggplotly()`, like so:

```
ggplotly(april_temp)
```

For some reason plotly is connecting points that have the same value instead of connecting them as a time series like before. It looks like this:
[Same plot, different result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjhYM.png)

What am I missing?

Comment: This is a difficult problem to solve without having the data to work with.  Most likely the x variable(hour) is not a numeric and most likely a character object or a factor.  When ggplot is plotting the values in one order (may alphabetical) while plotly is plotting the values in a different order - maybe in sequence.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the data and thanks for your comment! At first, I really had problems with the date and hour variables because it was classified as characters. I used `as.Date()` and `as_hms()` to convert date and hour. Is it possible plotly is still interpreting date and hour as characters even after conversion?

Comment: Sorry for not using reprex(). I'm still new to R I had some trouble installing the required packages to use it.

Comment: I would filter your original dataset down to 1 day (pick the worst looking chart from above) and see if you can reproduce the problem.  If you can, edit the question and post the output from the `dput()` function for this reduce dataset.  This should provide enough information to understand what is going.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ggplot` object is named `abril_temp`.  Just a typo.

Comment: Sorry, I translated my code from Portuguese to English to post here and forgot to change that. The code works fine here but I don't understand the issue with Plotly. I'll correct the post. Thanks.

Comment: You need to post a sample dataframe so that we can test it.  Reprex can include dummy data.